# How can I prevent VSCode from putting a strikethrough the btoa method?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, eslint

I have a sample project at https://github.com/eric-g-97477-vue/btoa
It is just the default vue 3 project.

VS Code is putting a strikethrough the [btoa](https://github.com/eric-g-97477-vue/btoa/blob/main/src/main.js) function and telling me it is deprecated. I would like to have it not do that.

I know that btoa is deprecated in node, but it is still supported in code running in the browser, which is where my code will be running.

I have tried playing around with .eslintrc and jsconfig.json, but nothing I have tried has been able to tell VSCode to not draw the strikethrough.

Who is responsible for the strikethrough? Is it eslint or just VSCode?

One solution I am aware of is writing the code as window.btoa, but I would like to just use btoa because I think it looks cleaner.

Is there a way to configure VSCode to correctly detect that it should not mark btoa as deprecated?

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45566 appears to be related to this. It mentions

> If you’re writing DOM code, you should really try to avoid having node typings in your program

It may be a solution to remove the node typings, but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: "I would like to just use btoa because I think it looks cleaner" unfortunately your wish can not be granted.  `window.btoa` is the correct way to use btoa on the frontend

Comment: Actually, it can. I need to do a bit more investigation, but I have it working. Will hopefully be able to write an answer soon.